# Add sidebar in MeanJS application

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I have an application being developed using MeanJS, which has a header, sidebar and actual content. With the template from the Meanjs we have header and content(data-view). 
So when we load url in the application the content is loaded with makes the sidebar and content window gets reloaded. Can I make the header and sidebar to be fixed always and content as data-view.
In MeanJS how to fix add the sidebar along with the header.

Any ideas on this. Please help (I will explain in detail if needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. All you have to do is to add your sidebar element in the layout.server.view.html file like this;

```
<header data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse"></header>

<aside class="sidebar">
    <!-- Load your partial views here -->
    <section data-ng-include="'/modules/your-custom-module/views/view-your-custom-module.client.view.html'"></section>
    <section data-ng-include="'/modules/another-custom-module/views/view-another-custom-module.client.view.html'"></section>
    <!-- ... -->
</aside>

<section class="content">
  <section class="container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </section>
</section>
```

Now the sidebar, as an element, will be persistent while its content will dynamically update depending on the scope data you load.

Comment: I have used the same solution and it works very well.